# Fixed element bahaviour isn't as expected

Tags: css, css-position

I have a case where the fixed element is 'positioned' - in a way - relative to the parent container and not the browser window...

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.options {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.options button {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="options">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div containing the buttons is fixed, and the bottom offset is set to 0. However, the div is offset a certain distance, and starts at the same horizontal distance as the parent container. Now once I set the left offset value to '0' the element positions itself as expected, starting from the edge of the viewport. So I understand that this isn't actually positioned in relation to the parent container. But why is there an offset initially? I'm guessing the default 'auto' setting computes that left value to something other than zero. But how is this value computed?

Also, another point of confusion arose with how the width value is computed, when the value is 100% vs inherit. I looked up and realized that the difference between the two is that while 'width: 100%' sets the width to 100% of the computed value of the parent element, 'width: inherit' takes up the CSS value of the parent literally and applies that to the element. So in the case of the sample I shared above, while the former will set the width of the div containing the buttons to literally 100% of its own parent's computed width, the latter will set to width to '640px', which is the parent's CSS value. The issue I have is, in the first case, where the width is set in percentages, the element is wider than expected. The computed width appears to be computed from the viewport width i.e. 100% of the viewport, and not the parent element, which is what I expected.

If 'width: inherit' acquires the width of 640px from the parent element, then why is the width inherited from the viewport if width is set to 100%, and not the computed value of the parent. Why is it that in one case, the preceding container is considered as the parent from which the value is inherited, and in the other case the viewport is the parent from which the value is computed?

Comment: What is your expected result. How the buttons should be arranged in respect of `container`.

Comment: **But why is there an offset initially?** Simple the fixed element is positioned relative to it's parent, the initial offsets comes from that, an initial value will be computed as if the element isn't fixed at all taking into account the position of the parent, padding, margin etc.., which is the case with all position values even `fixed`

Comment: **`percentage`** is relative to the containing block, that changes according to css rules, **`inherit`** keyword is relative to the parent element defined in the markup and that never changes with css

Comment: @decpk Since the fixed element is position relative to the viewport, I expected the element to be pushed to left: 0 from the edge, and since the parent element is 640px and the width of the div containing buttons is 100%, I expected that div to also be 640px. But I guess both those assumptions aren't right.

Comment: @ZohirSalak This makes so much sense. I had the false assumption that once an element is fixed it automatically goes to left:0 and top:0.

Comment: @ZohirSalak Both your answers are quite enlightening. This clears my doubts. If you'd post them as an answer I think I can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**But why is there an offset initially?**

That's the case with position values other than static and sticky (fixed, absolute) they keep their parent offsets.

**Demo:**

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

[container] {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

[absolute] {
  position: absolute;
}

[fixed] {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div absolute>absolute</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div container>
  <div fixed>fixed</div>
</div>
```

As you can see even with position applied, the elements don't suddenly jump around to where they're expected to be. You can try adding `left:0` add see how they move.

---

**Width: inherit or 100%; ?**

Like i said before:

> **percentage** is relative to the containing block, that changes according to css rules, inherit keyword is relative to the parent element defined in the markup and that never changes with css

Much more accurate MDN explanation

> Percentage values that are applied to the width, height, padding, margin, and offset properties of an absolutely positioned element (i.e., which has its position set to absolute or fixed) are computed from the element's containing block.

**Demo**

```css
[container] {
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate(0)
}

[fixed] {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div container>
  <div fixed>fixed</div>
</div>
```

In this example `width:100%` is behaving as it should because we changed the congaing block of the fixed element using `transform: translate(0)`

There's many ways to change the [**containing block**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) of an element i suggest you read up the MDN article on that.

Comment: This clears a lot of my doubts, thank you. I will look up more on the concept of containing block vs parent element. Also, I noticed that you used empty attributes and selectors based on that in your code snippet. Is that common practice?

Answer (score 0):

1. `body` have a padding per default. You can add `padding: 0` to make your fixed element go as far to the left as possible, or add `left: 0` to your fixed `.options` element.
2. You shouldn't use fixed width (640px), because you should code with responsiveness in mind.
3. You shouldn't use float in layout, because it mess up the box size of the object. Only use it on images if you want the text to "float" around the image.

```css
html, body {  /* ADDED */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; /* CHANGED */
  margin: 0 auto;

  /* ADDED */
  min-width: 640px;
}

.options {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*left: 0;  if you don't want to change the padding for the body */

  /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
}

.options button {
  /*float: left;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* width: 25%; */
  
   /* ADDED */
  flex: 1 1 auto;  /* grow / shrink / auto-adjust in width */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="options">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the issue isn't with the padding. I looked that up with the debugger and those values were zero. In fact, the behaviour is not an issue, the issue was with my understanding of some concepts. I will take your suggestion in relation to responsive design. As for 'floats', I'm relearning CSS, and I didn't realise that. I looked up online and there are a lot of  people suggesting the same. I will keep that in mind going forward :)

Comment: Do read what I commented  out for `.options`. As for absolute and fixed elements, it sometimes bugs out on Safari if you use `width: 100%`. You should instead set `left` and `right` to zero.

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I had tried that before and found that that resolves the issue, I've even mentioned that in my initial explanation. But my query was more to do with why that would be required, when 'position: fixed' takes the element out of flow. Now I understand that even if the element is out of flow, its position is computed based on it's position in normal flow, unless offset values are presented. But thank you for your help :)